# Some (hopefully) basic questions about big table management ( > 10 Billion rows) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, database-design, query-performance

I'm doing some experimentation with table design for a table that we expect to have *LOTS* of rows (upwards of 10 billion).  Some things that immediately come to mind:

- In what I call the 'Tall' table approach, each row will have one of about 25 'types', along with a value corresponding to this type.  Should I turn this into a 'wide approach' with a single row containing a NULLable column for a value for each type?  This isn't a great approach from a maintainability standpoint (what if I have to add more 'types'), but I am more concerned about performance, with size being a secondary consideration.
- Rows will have a date time stamp (probably a smalldatetime, since I should only need to the minute).  I've heard that I may be better off using an integer representation for the datetime, as opposed to the datetime itself, in the table.  I expect that this datetime will be used heavily in queries (maybe even to the extent that it is part of the clustered index).

My main concerns are query performance, then size, in that order.  Lots of data will be dumped into the table, but it won't change or grow much (maybe daily or monthly updates, but not a lot of updates and not anything that I would consider transactional).

Comment: The values corresponding to each type - do they have the same data type?

Comment: For the most part no, they are integers or numeric, although we could probably use an integer and have logic to manage the floating point part of the number (for example, for '123.45', store an integer '12345' and manage the logic outside of the data store to divide by 100.  I would think that this creates more problems than it solves, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may benefit from table partitioning. Both SQL Server and Oracle have good support for this functionality. Table partitioning allows you to keep one logical table that you will continue to query, but the DBMS actually breaks into several physical files that it maintains with rules that you specify. For example, you can have partitions based on date so rows that have a CreateDate that falls within 1990, 2000, 2010, or 2020 will be placed in their respective partition.

The DBMS also uses partitions to leverage parallelism and could improve performance on queries that span multiple partitions.

Outside of database partitioning, you won't see performance gains without sharding the table which is difficult to maintain and makes queries more complex.

[Microsoft documentation on partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Update:
When you are considering making use of an integer for your datetime to improve performance, it actually would if you place your index on the integer date. The reason for this is integers are easier to sort, so creating a B-Tree index will improve the overall speed of that particular index. However, if you aren't going to be querying using that column (within a where or group by clause), it is not recommended to just add indexes because you can. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if your index storage is larger than the size of your table.